# Dynamic pagination depending on the number of rows in mySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, pagination

I am trying to do a dynamic paging for my mySQL database. Results per page are 20, and the number of pages (displayed at the bottom) is dependent on `$totalPages`

I am currently having some trouble escaping strings after the `for-loop`. Can someone help me double check?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Spreadsheet");
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$total = $rows[0];
$totalPages = ceil($total/20);
$i=0;

$pages = "Pages :";

    echo $pages;

    for ($i; $i<$totalPages; $i++){
    echo "<a href=\"index.php?page='$i'rpp=20\">$i</a>";

    }
```

The results should look like this:

```
Pages: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc..
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What is the issue? What is it currently displaying? where does `$rpp` comes from and what is the value of  `$totalPages`

Comment: Output of $totalPages is 2291 (rows). I removed $rpp. I've set that value as 20, meaning, 20 results per page.

Comment: `<a href=\"index.php?page='$i'rpp=20\">$i</a>` would produce the following link (with $i==1) `<a href=\"index.php?page='1'rpp=20\">1</a>` which look like you are missing `&` and putting quotes around your page `int` value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for ($i; $i<$totalPages; $i++){
   echo '<a href="index.php?page='.$i.'&rpp=20">['.$i.']</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will accept your answer in 7 minutes. Thank you very much :-).

EDIT: If I want to display them as [1] [2] [3] [4] etc, how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you removed rpp then it should be

```
echo "<a href=\"index.php?page=".$i."\">".$i."</a>";
```